# 403 Forbidden error everytime I upload a new file

Tags: linux, file-upload, centos, server, file-permissions

So this is probably a server admin trick that I just have't learned yet - but I have an issue. I am constantly uploading more files (specifically images like .jpg, .png, .jpeg) to my server in the same directory everytime. Whenever I include those images on a webpage (normally, using an  html tag) I always get an error message that says "The server responded with 403 forbidden error".

Every time that happens I have to login remotely via ssh on my terminal, and then navigate to the folder, and then perform the same chown / chmod command so those images are then accessible publicly. Is there any way I can streamline this process so I don't have to keep running that command every time I upload a new photo to my images directory? That way every photo uploaded to my images directory from now on will automatically be publicly accessible and I won't get this 403 forbidden error? This is very tedious and causes headaches quite a bit for me so I was hoping you guys have answered a question like this before.

Thanks!

Comment: what permission have you given to your images directory ?

Comment: What are you using for uploading?

Answer (score 1):

if you would upload via web this would not happen, I imagine you upload files via FTP or SFTP on a public html folder. 
To fix this you should create a system account in the group of the web server user, the use that account to upload files on the web server directory.

On Linux/UNIX find out what is the group used by the web server (www-data usually), then create a user in that group with:

```
useradd -m -d /path/to/upload/folder -s /bin/bash -g www-data uploader
```

Then give it a password (or generate public key for authentication)

```
passwd uploader
```

At this point connect via SSH/SFTP with the newly created user "uploader" and you will see that files uploaded with that user will have ownership

```
-rw-r--r--  uploader     www-data
```

This should be enough to let the web server serve the content, otherwise check httpd error log and /var/log/audit/audit.log to see if SELinux is blocking httpd.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, so Unix.

Comment: I meant the remote server is Linux right? If you SSH probably yes